# React Native if condtion

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new in react native, How do i set condition that if the `password1` is not equal to `password2` the data will not updated and if `password1` is equal to `password2` the data will updated in the database? i already fetch the current password from my api, please refer in the image below. thanks in advance.

```
 const handleSubmit = async(valuesToSubmit) =>    {
    let finalValidationPassed=true;
    if(preventSubmit)
    {
      let _data = {
            intusersid: UserData.UsersId,
            Password:  valuesToSubmit['Password'],
      }
      console.log("_data",_data)
      //if passord1 is equal 2 password2
      if(finalValidationPassed)
      {
        setErrortext("");
         fetch(config.API_URL + '/user/update', {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify(_data),
          headers: {
            //Headers
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        })
        .then((response) =>  response.json().then(data=>({status:response.status, body:data})) )
        .then((response) => {
          
          if(response.status==200){
            setIsEdit(false);
            alert("Profile Updated!");
            refetch();
          }else{
            setErrortext(response.body[0]?.msg);
            setErrortext(response.body[0]?._msgerror);
          }
        }); 

      }
    
    }else{
      alert("Sorry, submission failed. Please check your data entries.");
    } 
  }

 <Formik
         enableReinitialize
          initialValues={ UserData }
          onSubmit={(values) =>{ handleSubmit(values)}}
        >
        {(props) => (
  
  <SafeAreaView>
    <View style={formStyles.SectionStyle}>
    <Text>CURRENT PASSWORD</Text>
      <TextInput
            name="Password"
            value={props.values['Password']}
            secureTextEntry={true}
            onChangeText={props.handleChange('Password')}
      />
    </View>
    <View style={formStyles.SectionStyle}>
      <Text>SET NEW PASSWORD</Text>
      <TextInput
            name="Password1"
            value={props.values.password1}
            onChangePassword1={password1}
      />
    </View>

    <View style={formStyles.SectionStyle}>
      <Text>CONFIRM NEW PASSWORD</Text>
      <TextInput
            name="Password2"
            value={props.values.password2}
            onChangePassword2={password2}
      />
    </View>
```

UPDATE i cant pass value of password2 and password1 to my handlesubmit

[image]

Comment: Can you show your state variables you used for maintaining TextInput text state? if condition: `if (password1 === password2)`. It is not part of `react-native` but `JS`See [docs- if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: Tangential but the statement `"i already fetch the current password from my api"` seems a bit scary... you shouldn't be able to fetch a raw password from an api as you should never store raw passwords in your database.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have mistake in onChangeText for pass1 &2
you used onChangePassword1 & onChangePassword2 instead, thats why!